# Посоветуйте менеджер пакетов с модерацией

Tags: безопасность, npm, yarn, bower

Нужно собирать фронт. После февраля 2022 года в менеджерах пакетов появились деструктивные модули, которые норовят снести все файлы с системы.

Модерация есть в `maven`, но java не очень хочется использовать

`npn, pnpm, yarn, yarn2, bower` - что из этого обеспечивает лучшую защиту от вредоносных пакетов?

Какие настройки нужно прописывать, чтобы сохранить файлы?

Comment: Это же не техническая, а чисто политическая проблема, все зависит от сиюминутной доброй (или злой) воли людей, наполняющих пакеты (и проводящих модерацию)

Comment: @avp Где-то модерация в принципе есть (maven), где-то ее в принципе нет (npm). А в pnpm? А в pip? Предположу, что часть угроз может быть отфильтрована автоматически, при желании